# Codeigniter Login check issue in construct / infinite loop

Tags: codeigniter, authentication, constructor, codeigniter-2, login-control

i need to check is user loged or not.

i have to many function in controller, so i check it in construct function. but its entering infinite loop.

problem is: infinite loop.

```
  function __construct()
    {
        parent:: __construct();
        $this->is_logged_in();
        $this->clear_cache();
    }



 function is_logged_in()
{
            if( !class_exists('CI_Session') ) $this->load->library('session');

    if( $this->session->userdata('login') )
    {
        $data['name'] = $this->session->userdata('username');       

    }
    else
    {
        redirect(base_url('admin/login'));
    }

}
```

i dont want to use `$this->is_logged_in()` in all functions/pages.

Comment: which controller it is? is it login controller or parent of login controller?

Answer (score 0):

The ugly hack would be:

```
function __construct()
{
    parent:: __construct();
    if (($this->uri->segment(2) == 'admin') && ($this->uri->segment(3) != 'login'))
        $this->is_logged_in();
    $this->clear_cache();
}
```

I'm sure there are better ways, and the segment parts might be off, look up http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html for more information.

Answer (score 0):

@Allan

It should be

```
function __construct()
{
    parent:: __construct();
    if (!($this->uri->segment(2) == 'admin' && $this->uri->segment(3) == 'login'))
        $this->is_logged_in();
    $this->clear_cache();
}
```

Check the if condition.

Comment: @pekyolu-maslak  Have tried above if condition ? `if (!($this->uri->segment(2) == 'admin' && $this->uri->segment(3) == 'login'))`

Answer (score 0):

You might want to create a core controller then do the checking there if you don't want to use it on all your functions or pages on `application/core`

```
class MY_Controller Extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    protected function _is_logged_in()
    {
        if( !class_exists('CI_Session') ) $this->load->library('session');

        if( $this->session->userdata('login') )
        {
        $data['name'] = $this->session->userdata('username');       

        }
        else
        {


       if ($this->uri->segment(2) == 'admin' && $this->uri->segment(3) !== 'login')
        redirect(base_url('admin/login'));
        }
    }
}
```

then extend it like: On all your controllers that you want to verify login, or you can put the 
`$this->_is_logged_in()` function directly at your `MY_Controller` forcing all controllers that extends it to be checked. It's Up to you

```
class admin Extends MY_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->_is_logged_in();
    }
}

class user Extends MY_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->_is_logged_in();
    }
}
```

I used protected so that only classes that extends `my_controller` can use it, and add un underscore at the name, so it can't be accessed via url

Comment: still its going to be infinite loop. its same as with my first solution

Comment: loop solved but now you can access al pages without login. there is no control.